# Javascript basic slider with DIV classes rather than images

Tags: javascript, slider

How do I use divs rather than IMAGES tags for this. I tried `getElementsByTagName("div")`, but they are in a `#slider-content` div. so I am having trouble getting them from slide1 slide2 - div classes. THANKS.

```
   window.onload = function() {


    function e(eel) {
return document.getElementById(eel);
    }

    function t(tel) {
return document.getElementsByTagName(tel);
    }

   // SLIDER
   var slider = e('slider'),
        sliderImages = slider.getElementsByTagName('img'),
        noOfImages = sliderImages.length,
        wheee, n = 0,
        sliderContent = e('slider-content'),
        move,
        imgWidth = (100 / noOfImages) + "%";

   function sliderInit() {
  sliderContent.style.width = (noOfImages * 100) + "%";
   for (var i = 0; i < noOfImages; i++) {
    sliderImages[i].style.width = imgWidth;
}
   }

   wheee = {
slide: function() {
        move = setInterval(function() {
        if (n < (noOfImages-1)) n++;
        else n = 0;
        sliderContent.style.marginLeft = "-"+n+"00%";
    }, 3000);
},

stop: function() {
    window.clearInterval(move);
}
   }

  wheee.slide();
  sliderInit();

  sliderContent.onmouseover = wheee.stop;
  sliderContent.onmouseout = wheee.slide;
  }
```

html:

```
   <div id="slider">
    <div id="slider-content">

        <div class="slide1">This is slide one</div><!-- slide one -->
        <div class="slide2">This is slide two</div><!-- slide one -->
        <div class="slide3">This is slide three</div><!-- slide one -->

    </div><!-- slide content -->
</div><!-- slider -->
```

CSS:

```
   #slider-content{
-webkit-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 1s ease-in-out;
   }
   .slide1{
background: #ff143f;
   }
   .slide2{
background: #424242;
   }
   .slide3{
background: #ff00d2;
   }
```

Comment: what plugin are you using?

Comment: post the complete code then

Comment: Can you post the basic HTML structure and remove JS code that is not a part of the problem? Also what is `e('slider')`?

Comment: Just added html, css and all of javascript.

Comment: when I change IMG to div, it doesn't move each individual slider. I've tried sliderImages = slider.getElementsByTagName('div') and it doesn't work how I would like it to

Comment: @Jamie there's no need to re-invent the wheel. Hundreds, if not thousands of high quality, highly customisable jQuery slideshow plugins are out there. Probably basic javascript too if you do not want to use a library. You'll save yourself a lot of pain...

Comment: Im looking for a pure javascript slider. no jquery. any suggestions mario?

Answer (score 0):

Using straight JavaScript, the easiest way is likely to add a name to the divs you want to control (i.e. `<div name="slider"></div>`) and then use

```
sliderImages = slider.getElementsByName('slider'),
```

The rest of your code should work with that.

Comment: sorry... typo - I meant `getElementsByName`